# geom_tile border outline but no tile outline

Tags: border

Relatively simple question: for a plotted set of data, I'd like to outline a relevant region while not outlining every tile. See picture below, where I want to have an outline around the orange region without outlining every individual tile (which is what happens if I set the "colour" command within geom_tile to something

[Map with relevant data in orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FscQC.png)